# Get the Group name which has GID=0

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, awk

I wanted to write a shell script in which it needs to give the group name whose GID=0.I used awk command like this,

```
awk -F ':' {$3==0} /etc/group | cut -d ':' -f1
```

It works fine in redhat,aix.But not worked in Solaris.
It throws error like 
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

I want to use /usr/bin/awk in solaris.How to modify this script according to old awk in solaris?

or can i use alternate approach to generalize this script in all linux platforms?

Comment: Try quoting the `awk` command script: `awk -F ':' '{$3==0}' /etc/group …`.

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
I tried that in solaris.It shows error like this.

Comment: Is there any other command other than awk to get the output  for this case?

Comment: That was quick. … … … … … … … … You could probably use `sed` or `perl`.

Comment: can we able to check the condition like if GID=0 print the group name using sed?

Comment: The answer is probably yes.

Comment: I am a newbee can you tell some outlined format to use sed to match this condition?

Comment: Try doing some independent research: `man`, Google. Just searching Super User will yield a few nuggets (but also some gravel).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below:

```
$ getent group "groupname"
```

or probably this might also work

```
$ awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: But the OP wants to find the group name given the GID (your `getent` command assumes that the group name is already known). And `/etc/passwd` is not a good place to get information about groups.

Comment: in aix getent is not available